# Python run one function multiple times at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous

I am writing one bot and it needs to run multiple instances: first you input how many you want:

```
instances = int(input('How many instances?: '))
```

Then the code will run one function (the main and only thing it does) and thats it.
The bot is just Selenium, if that is relevant in any way

Tldr: Need to execute one function *multiple times* but *at the same time*

I tried

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        executor.submit(functionname)
```

but the problem is that I need to input how many instances of the bot at the same time should be ran, and this way of adding lines is extremely janky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythons multiprocessing module should do what you want.
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Multiple processes can be called like this:

```
for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use loop for this and initialize with a constant value 1 if you want to run your function one time and also Use methods of start and join.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user-na!
What I did was

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num in range(instances):
        Process(target=functionname).start()
```